# What is the meaning of $ inside the component template string '$<input ...>'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am am trying to understand the meaning of the $ in this following example's template string:

```
Vue.component('currency-input', {
  template: '\
    <span>\
      $\
      <input\
        ref="input"\
        v-bind:value="value"\
        v-on:input="updateValue($event.target.value)">\
    </span>\
  ',
  props: ['value'],
  methods: {
    // Instead of updating the value directly, this
    // method is used to format and place constraints
    // on the input's value
    updateValue: function (value) {
      var formattedValue = value
        // Remove whitespace on either side
        .trim()
        // Shorten to 2 decimal places
        .slice(
          0,
          value.indexOf('.') === -1
            ? value.length
            : value.indexOf('.') + 3
        )
      // If the value was not already normalized,
      // manually override it to conform
      if (formattedValue !== value) {
        this.$refs.input.value = formattedValue
      }
      // Emit the number value through the input event
      this.$emit('input', Number(formattedValue))
    }
  }
})
```

**What is the purpose of $ here?**

**What is the meaning of `$<input ...>` inside  `<span>` in template string?**

Comment: It's a currency input component. The $ represents the USD. It's a literal string.

Comment: God :) !! Thanks.

Comment: The $ just in front of the input tag is just the character $. It will be output on-screen as the character $, no magic.

Comment: I was asking the '$' inside the <span>. And I have the answer now. I was trying to read too much in to it. It will just print as $ on browser when the component is rendered. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sometime the answer is the simplest of all. Haven't we all been stuck there :)